# Filter Elasticsearch by day of week and time

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index for businesses in Elasticsearch. Each document in the index represent a business, and each business has business_hours. I'm trying to allow a filter on the business hours using the day of the week and the time. For example,we'd like to be able to do a filter for *show we all business that are open Tuesday Evenings after 6:00PM*
I'm thinking that we should have a field with the following mappings:

```
  {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          
          "business_hours": {
                             "type": "date_range",
                            "format": "w'T'hh:mma"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Each document would then have an array of business_hours.
So a store that is open on Monday 9:00AM - 5:00PM, and Tuesday 9:30AM - 5:00PM would look like this:

```
POST my-index/_doc
    {
      "name": "My Store",
      "business_hours": [
        {
        "gte": "1T09:00AM",
        "lte": "1T05:00PM"
        },
        {
        "gte": "2T09:30AM",
        "lte": "2T05:00PM"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I tried to search this document and query for it, but the filter for the hours is not working, they look like theyre getting ignored....
Does Elasticsearch support filtering by a day of the week or does it need to be an actual datetime?

Here's the query I used. Its supposed to filter for business open on Wednesday but it returned the document above which only had business hours on Monday and Tuesday

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "business_hours": {
              "gte": "3T10:00AM",
              "lte": "3T05:00PM",
              "relation": "CONTAINS"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of using a `range` field is a good one. However, instead of a `date_range`, which works on absolute dates, I suggest using an `integer_range` field.

Since every day contains 1440 minutes, my suggestion would be to encode the opening hours into the number of minutes since midnight and prefix that number with the index of the day (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, etc). The formula to transform a given hour into minutes since midnight is pretty easy:

```
(60 * HH) + MM 

Note: HH is in 24 hours format, not AM/PM, but that's a detail
```

Taking your example above, it would yield this:

```
POST my-index/_doc
{
  "business_hours": [
    {
      "gte": 10540,       <--- Monday (1), 540 minutes after midnight
      "lte": 11020        <--- Monday (1), 1020 minutes after midnight
    },
    {
      "gte": 20570,       <--- Tuesday (2), 570 minutes after midnight
      "lte": 21020        <--- Tuesday (2), 1020 minutes after midnight
    }
  ]
}
```

That way the `range` query becomes an easy one which gets rid of any date-related issues. For instance, the query below retrieves the document above by searching for businesses that are open on Mondays between 6AM and 5PM

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "business_hours": {
              "gte": "10600",         <--- Monday (1), 600 minutes after midnight
              "lte": "11020",         <--- Monday (1), 1020 minutes after midnight
              "relation": "CONTAINS"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution Val! Just wondering, is there an advantage to using day appended as an integer appended ot the beginning   instead of just calculating the field as the number of minutes elapsed since Midnight on Saturday? This way Monday  (D) for 600 minutes after midnight would be (HH * 60) + (D * 1440) + MM = (10 * 60) + (1 * 1440) + 0 = 2040

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue with your mapping, sample data, and query and when I used [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9//search-search.html#request-body-search-explain) on the query, It explained why it was fetching the result for day 1 and day 2.

**Output of search query with explain**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_shard": "[64883176][0]",
                "_node": "kL6FUU3RT5GGzu_mqRs8NA",
                "_index": "64883176",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "My Store",
                    "business_hours": [
                        {
                            "gte": "1T09:00AM",
                            "lte": "1T05:00PM"
                        },
                        {
                            "gte": "2T09:30AM",
                            "lte": "2T05:00PM"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.0,
                    "description": "ConstantScore(business_hours:<ranges:[36000000 : 61199999]>)^0.0",
                    "details": []
                }
            }
        ]
```

If you notice carefully, the query is converted in epoch format as shown below

```
ConstantScore(business_hours:<ranges:[36000000 : 61199999]>)^0.0",
```

Now when you use the [epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) you can notice its actually making a range query on a completely different date range, starting range is  `Friday, 10 December 1971 07:59:59`

**According to the range query on the date field, Elasticsearch adds the [missing date component](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#missing-date-components) and this seems to be causing the issue.**

if you give the proper data range(ie complete date including year, month etc), obviously it works but I agree, this will lead to complexity, I will see how can we achieve the same thing with given format.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess a possible solution would be to just add an actual date to the business_hours, however it definitely feels hacky. It would be great if we can get the range to work with just a day of week and hours

Comment: @SGolds, yes thats definitly a possible solution which I also mentioned in my answer, also as I mentioned it will lead to complexity and I tried hard to find how it can be worked with just day of week and hours but couldn't find the solution even after spending couple of hours on this

Comment: Thanks for all the effort!